# How to remove Windows Operating system from Bootcamp?

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I have installed Windows 8 through BOOTCAMP, and now i want to remove it and leave it for a clear OSX. Is there anyone who know how to remove it completely? (I mean nothing related windows left).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple [helps](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH17861?viewlocale=en_US):

> **Boot Camp: Remove Windows from your Mac**
>
> How you remove Windows from your Mac depends on whether you installed Windows on a disk that has multiple partitions or one that has a single partition.
>
> Important: Back up all important data stored on your Windows partition.
>
> **If you installed Windows on a disk that has multiple partitions**
>
> 1. Start up your Mac in OS X.
> 2. Quit all open apps and log out any other users.
> 3. Open Boot Camp Assistant, then click Continue.
> 4. Select “Remove Windows 7 or later version,” then click Continue.
> 5. Do one of the following:
>
>    - If your Mac has a single internal disk, click Restore.
>    - If your Mac has multiple internal disks, select the Windows disk, select “Restore disk to a single OS X partition,” then click Continue.
>
> **If you installed Windows on a disk that has a single partition**
>
> 1. Start up your Mac in OS X.
> 2. Open Disk Utility, located in the Other folder in Launchpad.
> 3. Select the Windows disk, click Erase, choose the Mac OS Extended (Journaled) >format, then click the Erase button.

Answer (score 3):

- Launch the Boot Camp Assistant.
- Click the Continue button in the first screen.
- Select the Create or Remove a Windows Partition option in the next screen
- Click Continue again.
- Select the drive that has your Boot Camp partition, enable the Restore Disk to a Single Mac OS Partition option, and click Continue.
- You’ll be prompted for your administrator’s name and password.
- Click OK and Boot Camp Assistant will restore the disk to a single Mac OS partition.